Foam’s not showing properly with ocean
Using ocean modifier and dynamic paint in cycles, the foam looks ok in attribute view but not in Rendered animation. I suppose it's a material issue since I can the see the foam in attribute view. I have posted a screenshot. Anyone know how to generate alot of foam at the seashore and get it to show?

